# iOS UISearchController active?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, uisearchdisplaycontroller, uisearchcontroller

I am upgrading to the UISearchController (iOS8) which I followed from apple documentation. It is working as expected for one thing that I can't seem to find a solution for.

I am passing the search text to this SearchViewController that is inside the tableview and I would like to set the search view controller to be active if there was text. However, this does not seem to set it to true in viewDidLoad method.

```
if(![_searchText isEqualToString:@""]) {
        self.searchController.active = YES;
        self.searchController.searchBar.text = _searchText;
        NSLog(@"Active?: %d", self.searchController.active);
}
```

Active is false. Doing the same thing with UISearchDisplayController works but not UISearchController.

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried calling `becomeFirstResponder` on `self.searchController.searchBar`?